# WPF: How to create UserControl that renders controls passed as content

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to create "Expander" usercontrol that facilitates hiding (collapsing) another UI.

**Now I have this:**

*Expander usercontrol - XAML:*

```cs
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption, ElementName=root}"/>
        <ToggleButton Content="{Binding ToggleText}" IsChecked="{Binding Expanded}"/>
        <ContentControl Visibility="{Binding Expanded, Converter={x:Static root:GlobalConverters.BoolToCollapsedVisibilityConverter}}" Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=root}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

*Expander usercontrol - Code behind:*

```cs
    public Expander()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModels.ExpanderViewModel();
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(Expander), new PropertyMetadata("unkown caption"));
    
    public string Caption
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty);
        set => SetValue(CaptionProperty, value);
    }
    
    public new static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object[]), typeof(Expander), new PropertyMetadata(Array.Empty<EmptyContent>()));
    
    public new object[] Content
    {
        get => (object[])GetValue(ContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }
```

*Expander usage - View:*

```cs
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:OrdersListModeViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <controls:Expander Caption="Orders">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" />
        </controls:Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**I'm facing two issues:**

1. The designer is showing this error screen:
   [image: Designer error screen]
   I've tried removing obj and bin directories but it didn't help.
2. I'm getting binding errors within Expander.xaml:
   [image: Binding errors]
   I dont understand why the "controls:Expander" element content doesn't use its own datacontext

Comment: You know that there already is an Expander control in the framework, which you can style according to your needs? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/expander-overview

Comment: Besides that, a UserControl should *never* set its own DataContext, because that breaks the way how standard data binding of its properties works. Your `ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"` looks up the Orders properties in the private view model of the control instead of the DataContext passed to the DataTemplate. This is a programming error.

Comment: @Clemens I didn't know about this control I'll look at it but keep the scenario a want to create my own custom expander element (or other element that renders a content that was passed to it).

Comment: @Clemens So how do I achieve the usercontrol having its own state? I wouldn't call that as a programming error rather as "possible misunderstanding" of databinding mechanism in WPF. I assumed that <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" /> uses datacontext of to scope it's defined (in this example viewModels:OrdersListModeViewModel). If I understand you right: The issue is that when we pass a content to an element the content then uses the datacontext of the element it was passed to?

Comment: The UserControl must under no circumstance set its own DataContext. That is an error. Use Bindings with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}` in the UserControl's XAML. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972394/1136211, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29076685/1136211

Comment: A UserControl has its Content set to the top level element in its XAML declaration (i.e. the StackPanel here). When you set the Content to something else, the whole visual tree is replaced by the new Content and the original is lost. What you are trying to do here must be done in a ControlTemplate. When you do that, just set the Template property of the existing Expander control.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was really trivial and I needed some time to realise. Also some tips in the comments were also helpful.

I've created State property in user control code behind:

```
public partial class Expander : UserControl
{
    public Expander()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ExpanderViewModel State { get; } = new ExpanderViewModel();
}
```

Then I made binding to the State property using RelativeSource binding property

```
<ToggleButton Content="{Binding State.ToggleText,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
              IsChecked="{Binding State.Expanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Thank you for noticing not setting the usercontrol's DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, you would have to override the `ControlTemplate` so that the client of your control can use the `Content` property to define the actual content you want to host. Then you simply toggle the visibility of the `ContentPresenter`.

To enable customization, I recommend creating a custom control that extends `HeaderedContentControl` instead of using a `UserControl`.
`HeaderedContentControl` gives you a `Header` property and a `Content` property - exactly what you want.

However, because there already is a framework `Expander` control (that also extends `HeaderedContentControl`), you should extend `Expander` instead and add additional functionality to the existing one:

**MyExpander.cs**
Every control must never depend on its data context. A control must be data context agnostic. If you need external data then you must request it via public dependency properties. Internal elements will bind to those dependency properties to fetch their data.

This way the client of your control has full control over the `DataContext` and is able to feed the required data via data binding - without any surprises (for example, bindings fail because the control internally changes the `DataContext`!).

```cs
class MyExpander : Expander
{
  static MyExpander()
  {
    // You can remove this if you only need to add behavioral functionality
    // but want to keep the original visuals and visual states.
    FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(MyExpander),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyExpander)));
  }

  // TODO::Add new functionality to the existing Expander
}
```

**Generic.xaml**
Example template. Only needed when the default style is explicitly overridden from the static constructor. You can see how the `ContentPresenter` is collapsed or visible based on the `Expander.IsExpanded` property:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyExpander}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Style.Resources>

  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyExpander}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
            <ContenPresenter Grid.Row="1" 
                             Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResourtce BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>

  <!-- Either inherit or explicitly set the DataContext -->
  <MyExpander DataContext="{Binding ExpanderViewModel}" 
              Header="Expandable content"
              IsExpanded="True">
    <ListBox />
  </MyExpander>
```

Comment: In the question the Expander is declared in a DataTemplate, so assigning its DataContext is pointless. It would be inherited. Besides that `DataContext="{ExpanderViewModel}"` is invalid syntax.

Comment: It is also unclear why you would create a derived control when you only want to set its Template.

Comment: Sorry, I had a bad sleep. I was just showing that we set the data context from the client code and not from within the control. He was previously setting `ExpanderViewModel` as the control's `DataContext` from the constructor of this control. I just moved it to the client code. I showed how to extend the existing `Expander` in case he wants to add his own functionality.

Comment: This answer may or may not be relevant I don't know. I originally wanted to show how to properly template an expander control. I don't expect this to be a useful answer (except learning his mistakes) as he most likely can use the existing `Expander`. I just wanted to show where he went wrong with his original approach. For example, extending `UserControl` instead of `HEaderedContentControl` (or `Expander`)